# How to start learning management

Tags: management, training

I was recently offered an opportunity to move from individual contributor to manager.  I have no experience as a manager.

I asked my manager for recommendations about how to learn management, but was told that (a) there's no such training and (b) was offered a couple books (~100 pages each) to read.  I checked with our training department, and my company doesn't offer any management training.

The harvard business school exists, so clearly there's management training in the world - but I don't want to go get a second degree (yet)

How can I get started?  What are the best management training resources and why might I choose one resource vs another?

Answer (score 5):

Congratulations! and best wishes.

A place I worked actually offered me some management training.  Here's what I remember.

- Never, **ever**, even once, joke or make offhand references about a person's pay. If you do you *will* be sorry.
- Supervising people is a real trade, and it's harder to learn than various technical trades like programming, flying airplanes, cooking, whatever. Good supervisors never stop learning.
- Give the credit and take the blame.
- All of management comes down to two tasks. Neglect either one at your peril.

  1. Make sure everybody wants to do the right thing.
  2. Let everybody do whatever they want.

Some other things I've learned along the way.

- You can be kind without being weak.

  - Sometimes it's kind to fire somebody if they're not suited to the job. It's kind to the person you fire and kind to the rest of your team.
- If you approach people-problems curiously rather than critically, you'll find them easier to solve.
- Some people you supervise will be afraid of you, it comes with the job.  So, they will hesitate to talk to you straight about things. Read lots of questions and answers here on Workplace, and you'll be amazed how many answers boil down to "have a conversation about that." Talk to people about how they're doing. A lot.
- You can't do the job perfectly. All you can do is your best.
- It takes time for people to absorb challenging ideas (criticism, suggestions, changes in company direction). Give people time. They aren't going to slap their foreheads and say "wow, you're right and I'm wrong."
- It takes time for **you** to absorb challenging ideas. Remember that.
- Don't make promises unless you *know for sure* you can keep them (pay raises, vacation, future assignments, anything).

What can you read? There's tons of stuff. Ask your local public librarian. Seriously. And, ask your fellow managers for advice about how to learn more.

Beware trendy business books: they have both good and bad ideas.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get started?

You can get started by actually being a manager and learn on the job. Since you are already promoted, there is not enough time for you to read books and apply it. (At least not in the short term). Try to learn from your own experiences on what went right and what went wrong. Someone in the company thought you can handle this so may be they saw something in you. Let that quality come out on its own.

> What are the best management training resources and why might I choose one resource vs another?

This is highly debatable and there cannot be any right answer for it. However, any low cost or free courses on MOOC platforms like coursera or edx from reputed universities could be a good start to prepare yourself for the long run.

Comment: I would add that many managers learn over the years in non-managerial roles. I went from leading a team of 4, to building up a team of 12, to being a personnel manager. I did have classes along the way to help with the "non-managerial leadership roles", but mostly I learned from the moment my then-manager told me I was responsible for several other engineers.